# Cannot refresh DataGrid in WPF using PRISM 5, MVVM, and EF 6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

My problem seems to be a common one, yet, for all of the posts I have read - both here and on other sites - I STILL have not found a solution.

I have a fairly simple data-entry WPF module - 2 TextBoxes, 3 ComboBoxes, 1 DataGrid, and then Submit and Clear buttons.  (The app/form is for creating general ledger accounts in an accounting db.)  I am builing my entire solution using PRISM 5.  (This is my first foray into anything remotely this complicated, and it is, at the moment, a proof-of-concept endeavor.)  Anyway, Iam binding all WPF screens (UserControl/Views) to appropriate ViewModels.  The ViewModel in turn obtains its data from a MSSS db via EF 6 entities (DB First).  When the user opens this particular WPF screen the DataGrid shows all existing records in the database.

With one exception the Submit (new record) procedure works as I want:  a new entry is pushed through to the MSSS db, the text boxes are cleared, and the ComboBoxes reset.  What I then want, however, is 1) the DataGrid to refresh, showing the new record, and 2) for that new record to be highlighted in the grid.  For the life of me I cannot get that working, though.  NOTE:  It may make some difference that the DataGrid is bound to a view, rather than to a table, in the db.  (Again, that DataGrid displays correctly when the app first opens.)

So, how do I get the DataGrid to update?????

Here is the (condensed) XAML for the WPF view:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="AcctMappingWpfModule.Views.CreateGLAcctsView"
         other namespace declarations...
         xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:AcctMappingWpfModule.ViewModels">
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <vms:CreateGLAcctsViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    ... 
    <StackPanel ...>
    <!-- Layout controls for 2 Text boxes & 3 ComboBoxes -->
        ...
    <!-- Data grid of all Genl Ledger accts -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgGLAccts" 
        IsReadOnly="True"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        ...
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GLAccounts}" />
    <WrapPanel >
        <!-- Submit & Clear Buttons here -->
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the (condensed) ViewModel code (try/catch blocks omitted):

```
    namespace AcctMappingWpfModule.ViewModels
```

{
    public class CreateGLAcctsViewModel : BindableBase, ICreateGLAcctsViewModel
    {
        private TBLOADEntities context;
        private int _glAcctID = 0;
    // Other private fields...

```
// Ctor...
    public CreateGLAcctsViewModel( )
    {
        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSubmit);

        // Populate ICollectionViews - i.e., properties...
        using (context = new TBLOADEntities())
        {
            // 3 properties behind ComboBoxes populated, then the DataGrid ppt...
            List<vwGLAcct> accts = new List<vwGLAcct>();
            accts = (from a in context.vwGLAcct select a).ToList<vwGLAcct>();
            GLAccounts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(accts);
        }

        // Hook up selection change delegates, including...
        GLAccounts.CurrentChanged += GLAccounts_CurrentChanged;
    }

    private void OnSubmit()
    {
        GLAccount glAcct = new GLAccount()
        {
    // Various properties set, then...
            GlFsAcctTypeComboFK = this.SelectedFSAcctTypeComboID
        };
        using (context = new TBLOADEntities())
        {
    context.GlAcct.Add(glAcct);
    context.SaveChanges();
    // vwGLAcct is the EF entity of the MSSS db view...
    List<vwGLAcct> accts = new List<vwGLAcct>();
            accts = (from a in context.vwGLAcct select a).ToList<vwGLAcct>();
            GLAccounts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(accts);
            SelectedGLAcctID = glAcct.GlAcctID;
            GLAccounts.Refresh();
    }
    }

    private void GLAccounts_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vwGLAcct current = GLAccounts.CurrentItem as vwGLAcct;
        SelectedGLAcctID = current.GlAcctID;
    }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }

    public int SelectedGLAcctID
    {
        get
        { return _glAcctID; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _glAcctID, value);
        }
    }

    public ICollectionView GLAccounts { get; private set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you getting the default view again? (CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(accts)) after the submit? make sure the accts is an ObservableCollection and get the default view only once, then hit refresh it.

2) is that the code behind of the Window? if so, dgGLAccts.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget()

Comment: 1)  Running refresh() alone on GLAccounts doesn't do anything (at least not anything that shows up in the view).  I'm recreating the default view thinking that I need to 're-query' the view in MSSS.  (Obviously without luck, though.)

Comment: 2) No, the C# code is the code in the view model.  As is standard with MVVM the only code behind the window is an InitializeComponent(); call within the ctor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing these from yours to mines

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="dgGLAccts" 
              IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGLAccount}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GLAccounts}" />

    private vwGLAcct selectedGLAccount;
    public vwGLAcct SelectedGLAccount
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedGLAccount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedGLAccount != value)
            {
                selectedGLAccount = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedGLAccount);
            }
        }
    }

    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<vwGLAcct> gLAccounts;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<vwGLAcct> GLAccounts
    {
        get
        {
            return gLAccounts ?? (gLAccounts = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<vwGLAcct>());
        }
    }

public CreateGLAcctsViewModel( )
{
    this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSubmit);

    // Populate ICollectionViews - i.e., properties...
    using (context = new TBLOADEntities())
    {
        // 3 properties behind ComboBoxes populated, then the DataGrid ppt...
        List<vwGLAcct> accts = new List<vwGLAcct>();
        accts.ForEach(a => this.GLAccounts.Add(a));
    }
}

private void OnSubmit()
{
    GLAccount glAcct = new GLAccount()
    {
// Various properties set, then...
        GlFsAcctTypeComboFK = this.SelectedFSAcctTypeComboID
    };
    using (context = new TBLOADEntities())
    {
context.GlAcct.Add(glAcct);
context.SaveChanges();
// vwGLAcct is the EF entity of the MSSS db view...
this.GLAccounts.Add(glAcct);
this.SelectedGLAccount = glAcct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Change your GLAccts to be an on `ObservableCollection` of whatever your account class is, in your ViewModel. And don't forget the `NotifyPropertyChanged`

(2) Put the CollectionViewSource, if that's what you need, in your xaml, and bind your VM property to the source there, like this:

`<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding GLAccts}" x:Key="AccountsCollection" >`

(3) You can then binding your datagrid to that collection like this:

`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AccountsCollection}}" ...`

Whenever you make changes to items in that GLAccts property, and have submitted changes, just refresh it with another load on your context.

For dealing with the latest addition being the selected/highlighted one in the datagrid, you'll just have to set up a binding to a new VM property called `SelectedAccount` (or similar) and on the DataGrid have `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}"`

When you submit a new item you could keep hold onto that item as the SelectedAccount, or maybe on refresh of the whole collection you can work out which is the new item (by key or something).